# Did Turkey obtain external help in developing their jet engine?

Tags: turkey

Recently, Turkey unveiled a turbofan jet engine designated TF-6000. This engine is able to generate 6000 lbf of thrust, which is pretty good in my opinion, as the Taiwanese [jet fighter, Ching Kuo,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AIDC_F-CK-1_Ching-kuo#Specifications_(F-CK-1A)) uses double 6100 lbf jet engines.

Did Turkey build this from its own research and know-how or did they obtain help from other countries, e.g., Ukraine?

**Note:** [Ivchenko and Motor Sich engines have a much lower thrust than that of TF-6000](https://www.overtdefense.com/2021/11/12/baykar-puts-in-an-order-for-ai322f-and-ai25tlt-jet-engines-from-ukraine-for-mius/)

Comment: Why do you say that Ivchenko Progress' engines have a much lower thrust? E.g. the AI-222 has 5,500 lbf (>9,000 lbf with afterburner), which is similar. They also have engines with higher thrust (e.g. D-436 with 16,865 lbf), so why shouldn't they be able to help with something in between?

Comment: @Robe, I don't know. You tell me. If Ukraine had helped Turkey, they would have disclosed it to the media as their company's advertisements. The engines Turkey is purchasing have lower thrust. Other engines you are talking about do not match the amount of thrust.

Comment: Companies don't always disclose their cooperations, especially with sensitive issues like military capabilities. Perhaps Turkey wants to show the development as an inhouse achievement and asked Progress not to make publicity about it, but we can only speculate about it.

Comment: Your one-sentence question in the middle should be deleted and asked as its own question. We adhere to a reasonably strict "one question per question" policy - also, note that nobody has addressed it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the article at:https://www.turdef.com/Article/tei-has-an-engine-surprise-for-kizilelma/1736

> The engine will produce a trust similar to Ivchenko Progress and Motor
> Sich’s AI-322F engine. The engine was planned to be used at Baykar
> Technogy’s MIUS (Kızılelma) Combat Unmanned Aircraft System. The
> engine is also suitable for the Turkish Aerospace ( TUSAŞ) Hürjet
> Project. According to the TEI’s statement, the engine might also work
> on supersonic platforms.
>
> Baykar and Ivchenko-Progress had signed in November 2021 at
> SahaExpo2021 AI-322F Turbofan Engine Supply and AI-25TLT Turbofan
> Engine Integration contracts.

Thereby probably safe to say that some help from Ukraine in designing the engine was obtained.

Comment: [Ivchenko and Motor Sich engines have a much lower thrust than that of TF-6000](https://www.overtdefense.com/2021/11/12/baykar-puts-in-an-order-for-ai322f-and-ai25tlt-jet-engines-from-ukraine-for-mius/)

Comment: @user366312 Currently the TF-6000 has no thrust at all - they are working on the prototype and the 6000 lbs are a paper value. OTOH, increasing thrust of an existing design a bit is very common in engine development.